# How does Do Not Disturb work in iOS with message Favorites?

Tags: ios, do-not-disturb, phone.app

New in iOS 10 you can add a message favorite instead of just phone favorites. How does that work with Do Not Disturb's only allow notifications from favorites? If I add just a contact's phone but not their message info to my favorites will I only get calls from them in the middle of the night or will I receive message notifications as well? Asked another way, do I need to add each method of contacting a person to my favorites in order to get those notifications?

Answer (score -1):

**If their chat settings are not included in their Apple ID then you will need to add the corresponding info.**

I do not have an iPhone and use Messages desktop version, so the only way would be to add my chat info in your contact settings for me to send messages when DND is enabled.

Best practices would be to add all levels of contact info, or ask every contact what info is part of their Apple ID, if you do not already know. That doesn't sound fun.

Keep in mind that it will still silence the alert for incoming messages.

---

If you want to completely allow a user to get through at all times, simply override all DND settings via Emergency Bypass.

**NOTE:** You have to enable Emergency Bypass for each contact individually.

---

**How to turn on Emergency Bypass on iPhone and iPad**

1. Launch Contacts from your Home screen.
2. Tap on the contact you want to enable Emergency Bypass for.
3. Tap Edit.
4. Tap Ringtone (for calls) or Text Tone (for texts).
5. Tap the Emergency Bypass switch. The switch should be green when
   it's enabled.
6. Tap Done
7. Tap Done again.